# Having logo and text in same line - twitter bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Making the logo and text responsive across all resolution and size. I am having a problem where my text gets collapsed when i re-size my browser. How can i ensure that the logo and the text next to is in `same line` for all `resolution` and `sizes`.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Header</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.1.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.6/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="slider.js"></script>
  <style>
    .divider-vertical {
            height: 50px;
            margin-top: 0;
            margin-bottom: 0;
            margin-left: 20px;
            margin-right: 10px;
            border-left: 1px solid #a8a8a8;
            border-right: 1px solid #a8a8a8;
        }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container-fluid">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
        <div class="col-sm-3">
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">BimAssure</a>
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
              <li class="divider-vertical"></li>
              <li><h4 style="margin-top: 15px">ACME - New York</h4></li>
           </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Below is the fiddle i am being working on. I want the logo and text to be in same line across all resolution and sizes.
http://jsbin.com/yuhibisu/4/edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need to change this

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li class="divider-vertical"></li>
```

To this:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav divider-vertical">
    <li> ...
```

you have to apply the style to the "ul" and not the "li"

Check it:

http://jsbin.com/yuhibisu/8/edit

Comment: Well, it fails when there's no room for the full word...that's normal. Maybe you should change the font-size when the window width becomes to small

Comment: If you notice the vertical divider line is causing the problem when i re-size....

Comment: .navbar-brand{
        margin-left:20px; 
    } , maybe

Comment: Thanks, can you just help me in this http://jsbin.com/yuhibisu/10/edit where i can change the font size on sm and xs device. I tried, but its not working.... thanks for the hint on font-size.

Comment: You are using the @media in a wrong way. Also, you're calling the body. It's better to call ".navbar ul li h4" to specify just the navbar lettering.. check it here http://jsbin.com/yuhibisu/11/edit

Comment: Now, you just have to make the changes that you need in respect to margin, color, etc. I hope it helps ;-)